# UDP `join_multicast` results in OtherIOError

Tags: udp, rust, multicast

I am trying to join a KNX multicast group (ip: 224.0.23.12; port:3671) but receive an `OtherIoError`.

The socket connection appears OK since I can send to the multicast group (checked by Wireshark). To be sure, I tested with only one network interface activated and tried to replace the local_addr with 127.0.0.1 as well as the local IP address. My Rust version is `0.13.0-nightly (5ba610265 2014-12-25 18:01:36 +0000)` running on Windows 7 (64bit).

Similar code works in Go as well with other software joining this multicast group.

```
use std::io::net::udp::UdpSocket;
use std::io::net::ip::{Ipv4Addr, SocketAddr};

fn main() {
    let local_addr = SocketAddr { ip: Ipv4Addr(0, 0, 0, 0), port: 3671 };
    let mut socket = match UdpSocket::bind(local_addr) {
        Ok(s) => s,
        Err(e) => panic!("couldn't bind socket: {}", e),
    };
    match socket.join_multicast(Ipv4Addr(224, 0, 23, 12)) {
        Err(why) => println!("! {}", why.kind),
        Ok(_) => {},
    };
    drop(socket)
}
```

Comment: I ran this code on OS X, and I did not see any errors printed out. Perhaps this will be a platform-specific issue? As an aside, you don't need the `drop(socket)` - the socket will be closed as soon as the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: If I change `why.kind` to `why`, I get this error: `OS Error 10042: An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call.`

Comment: For anyone who comes across this question in the future, `join_multicast` has been [deprecated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.3.0/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.join_multicast) and later removed from `std`, and the functionality moved to [`join_multicast_v4`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/net2-rs/net2/trait.UdpSocketExt.html#tymethod.join_multicast_v4) and [`join_multicast_v6`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/net2-rs/net2/trait.UdpSocketExt.html#tymethod.join_multicast_v6) in the [`net2` crate](https://crates.io/crates/net2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think this is a bug in Rust.

This [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257460/en-us) says:

> Note that this includes Winsock.h. If the project is linked with Ws2_32.lib, setsockopt will fail with runtime error 10042 (WSAENOPROTOOPT). This is because in Winsock.h, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP is defined as "5". The corresponding Winsock runtime can not resolve option 5 at the IPPROTO_IP level, so the failure occurs with error code 10042.

The Rust constants [are defined](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/ead198c5133fd649d1e385cfc46f344a2baaef8b/src/liblibc/lib.rs#L2167-L2168) as 5 and 6, so perhaps someone grabbed the wrong constants from somewhere? I'll probably file an official Rust bug for this.